# using Boost Graph Lib with EMBARCADERO RAD C++ XE 5

Tags: c++, boost, delphi-xe5

I want to write a program using BOOST C++ lib and using RAD XE 5 compiler.

If  I import the boost libs with :

```
#include <boost_1_50/boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost_1_50/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost_1_50/boost/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost_1_50/boost/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>
```

I receive the following error msg

***[bcc64 Fataler Fehler] config.hpp(26): 'boost/config/user.hpp'-Datei nicht gefunden***

I have a lot of user.hpp files inside my Boost folder.

The error comes from config.hpp file :

```
// include it first:
#ifdef BOOST_USER_CONFIG
#  include BOOST_USER_CONFIG
#endif
```

How to include boost lib correctly at C++ XE 5 ? (for more info my Compiler settings as screen dump)

[image: C** screen dump]

here come a complete not compiling sample code

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit_shortpath.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"


#include "stdafx.h"


#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <boost_1_50/boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost_1_50/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/dijkstra_shortest_paths.hpp>



TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
```

/

Comment: Any chance here to get some help ?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot but notice that your #includes like

```
   #include <boost_1_50/boost/config.hpp>
   #include <boost_1_50/boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
   #include <boost_1_50/boost/adjacency_list.hpp>
```

are incorrect:

A. You should never include "config.hpp" directly, leave it to boost.

B. You should tune your path in such a way that includes do not mention Boost version

```
   #include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
   #include <boost/adjacency_list.hpp>
```

Most likely reason for your troubles is that because of your #include style you mess up two versions of Boost together.

Support for your compiler (Embarcadero, former Borland, right?) is not very consistent in new versions of Boost. It can be that Boost installation could not deduce some properties limitations and optimizations of this compiler. Boost developers do not even know how to retrieve its version: http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2013/09/206546.php.

Most likely you'll have to do it on your own, or maybe consult some compiler documentation, how to use Boost with it. You may even want to switch to older versions of Boost (1.49?) when compiler (or its predecessor) was supported.

Answering your specific question, to disable *user* config header, you can `#define BOOST_NO_USER_CONFIG` in your compiler settings. But if you have to do it, most likely you are already in serious troubles.

Comment: RAD Studio XE 5 should support Boost 1_50 in X64 bit mode and Boost 1_34 in X32 bit mode.  Also using the #include <boost/graph/xxxxxxx.hpp>  could not even compile an empty project as he clains file not found ....

Comment: "Also using the #include <boost/graph/xxxxxxx.hpp> could not even compile an empty project as he clains file not found" -- this is exactly my point! Your include settings are incorrect and it mess the things up. Tune the settings and make sure your compiler finds the files in boost 1.50 when you use `#include <boost/graph/xxxxxxx.hpp` Good luck!